# Oracle Data integrator : Oracle Merge

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I'm facing issues with some ODI mapping when using IKM : Oracle Merge . It works fine for some of the mappings. When I changed the IKM to Incremental Update, it worked.

Below is a piece of SQL code generated by ODI for a working mapping

```
MERGE_SUBQUERY
  ON
  (
    USER_SETTINGS1.USER_ID = MERGE_SUBQUERY.USER_ID 
  )
```

For the ones that are not working , MERGE condition is missing.I have defined the primary keys in the model and it is working fine when IKM is set to Incremental update.

```
MERGE_SUBQUERY
  ON
  (

  )
```

Have anyone experience similar issues with Oracle Merge ?

Thanks
Jeffrey

Comment: Which version of ODI are you using? Is it a template KM or a component KM?

Comment: @JeromeFr ODI 12 C and Component KM

Answer (score 1):

In your mapping, make sure the USER_ID column of the target (USER_SETTINGS1) has the "Key" checkbox selected in the properties pane. It looks like the IKM Oracle Merge is only looking at the UK flag and not the PK.